# DC-OS vagrant web GUI not available

Tags: web-services, vagrant, vmware, dcos

I installed dc-os vagrant on my VMware Workstation, everything seems fine after setup with command "vagrant up" (see tail log below).

```
############################# "vagrant up" log
...

==> p1:       Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dcos-setup.service to /etc/systemd/system/dcos-setup.service.
==> a1:       Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dcos-setup.service to /etc/systemd/system/dcos-setup.service.
==> p1: DC/OS Postflight
==> p1: [sudo]$ dcos-postflight
==> a1: DC/OS Postflight
==> m1: DC/OS Postflight
==> a1: [sudo]$ dcos-postflight
==> m1: [sudo]$ dcos-postflight
==> p1: Setting Mesos Memory: 1024 (role=slave_public)
==> p1: [sudo]$ mesos-memory 1024 slave_public
    p1:       Updating /var/lib/dcos/mesos-resources
==> p1: Restarting Mesos Agent
==> p1: [sudo]$ bash -ceu "systemctl stop dcos-mesos-slave-public.service && rm -f /var/lib/mesos/slave/meta/slaves/latest && systemctl start dcos-mesos-slave-public.service --no-block"
==> a1: Setting Mesos Memory: 5632 (role=*)
==> a1: [sudo]$ mesos-memory 5632
    a1:       Updating /var/lib/dcos/mesos-resources
==> a1: Restarting Mesos Agent
==> a1: [sudo]$ bash -ceu "systemctl stop dcos-mesos-slave.service && rm -f /var/lib/mesos/slave/meta/slaves/latest && systemctl start dcos-mesos-slave.service --no-block"
==> boot: DC/OS Installation Complete
==> boot: Web Interface: http://m1.dcos/
############################# "vagrant up" log
```

But when I try to access m1.dcos or 192.168.65.90 thru web browser, the website is not availble.
When I do curl command "curl http://192.168.65.90", below log also shows it's not available.

```
############################# curl http://192.168.65.90
[root@localhost dcos-vagrant]# curl http://192.168.65.90

<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Network Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big><strong></strong></big><BR>
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>Network Error (tcp_error)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>
For assistance, contact your network support team.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>
############################# curl http://192.168.65.90
```

When I ping the m1.dcos it's fine.

```
############################# ping
[root@localhost dcos-vagrant]# ping 192.168.65.90
PING 192.168.65.90 (192.168.65.90) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.65.90: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.518 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.65.90: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.721 ms
^C
--- 192.168.65.90 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.518/0.619/0.721/0.104 ms
[root@localhost dcos-vagrant]# 
[root@localhost dcos-vagrant]# 
[root@localhost dcos-vagrant]# ping m1.dcos
PING m1.dcos (192.168.65.90) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from m1.dcos (192.168.65.90): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.821 ms
^C
--- m1.dcos ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.821/0.821/0.821/0.000 ms
############################# ping
```

I can also ssh to node m1 as vagrant.
I am wondering which part I am missing or which service is having issue?

Comment: Is this with the official Vagrantfile and VMWare specified as the provider?

Comment: I am using VMware workstation 12 player, and vagrant is official dcos-vagrant from github.

Comment: Just figured out it has to do with proxy settings, now I changed etc/config-1.9.yaml to add proxy setting to disable proxy for local dcos url. and It worked!  Only thing I am getting now is auth error from website, and I am looking at it, this should be a separate thing though.